# Do children with Willam's Syndrome (WS) skip the the phase of "stranger-anxiety"?

Tags: social, developmental-milestones

Stranger anxiety is a normal phase in the developmental process of an infant, which reaches its apex, more or less, between 6-12 months in age (though it may certainly linger longer). While as parents,we often get embarrassed when we bring the in-laws, best friends, coworkers, and neighbors around and our children are screaming their heads off out of fear -- the "stranger-anxiety" phase is very typical, and assumingly an evolutionary trait that we as humans have kept because of the proverbial "stranger-danger" sentiment.

However, **I was wondering if children who have been diagnosed with Willam's Syndrome (WS) skip the "stranger-anxiety" phase all together?** Yes, William's Syndrome has a long list of physical and mental abnormalities, but **they are also known for being excessively (abnormally so) friendly and social... so are they developmentally delayed in the sense that they skip the "stranger-anxiety" milestone?** OR do they not start becoming more extroverted until they are older? (Read more about Willian's Syndrome here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Williams_syndrome).

**Since apparently that have a great memory of faces, then they indeed recognize that they are in the presence of a stranger, but this does not stir fear in them in any way, right?** My friend's daughter has WS (never had the chance to see if her daughter skipped the "stranger-anxiety" phase as a baby), but I know that my friend is always keep a constant eye on her daughter in fear that her daughter may be abundantly social and trusting and make herself vulnerable to kidnapping and other horrendous incidents.

**Why are people with WS so extroverted? Why do they display a strong sense of empathy?**